# javafx ImageView how to use css hover

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have made some custom buttoms with the JavaFX using ImageView

```
<ImageView fitHeight="25.0" fitWidth="25.0" onMouseClicked="#doExit" onMouseEntered="#doHighLight" onMouseExited="#doReset" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" fx:id="xIcon">
    <image>
        <Image url="@imges/icons/x.png" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

in order to do highlighting I have used mouse listeners

```
public void doHighLight(){
    //System.out.println(xIcon.getImage());
    Image itmp= new Image("/gui/imges/icons/xSelected.png");
    xIcon.setImage(itmp);
    //xIcon.setImage(new Image("./imges/icons/x.png"));
    }

public void doReset(){
    xIcon.setImage(new Image("/gui/imges/icons/x.png"));
}
```

As you can see it not the best way to do it so I have tried some css but its not working. Why?

```
#xIcon:HOVER {
    -fx-image: url('@../imges/icons/xSelected.png');
}
```

the file locations are as follows :

```
/app/GuiController.java
/gui/style/main.css
/gui/imges/icons/x.png
/gui/imges/icons/xSelected.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons for not being worked:

1) Set `id = "xIcon"` for ImageView. `fx:id` and `id` are different attributes.
2) You can't use `@` for location resolution. In FXML file yes but not in CSS (JavaFX) file.
3) It seems the pseudo-classes are not case insensitive. So use `:hover` instead of `:HOVER`.

For more information please refer to JavaFX's CSS reference guide.

Comment: does `are not case insensitive` intentionally cover some extra meaning? otherwise `are case sensitive` seems to be more straightforward.

Comment: @naxa good catch :). It was in a context of question, such that the OP tried to use the case insensitive approach for pseudo-classes, and so the answer was "are not case insensitive". No extra meaning.